# specified type member FullName is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: linq, entity-framework

Im getting the error"specified type member FullName is not supported in LINQ to Entities" when using select d.FullName, is it because it is not part of the table?

How do I fix this?

Thanks

USER CLASS

```
public partial class tblUser
{
    public tblUser()
    {
        this.Equipment = new HashSet<tblEquipment>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public string FullName { get { return Forename + " " + Surname; } }
```

QUERY WITH ERROR

```
string[] arrUsers = (from d in db.tblUsers select d.FullName).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to select it manually:

```
string[] arrUsers = (from d in db.tblUsers select (d.Forename ?? "") + " " + (d.Surname ?? "")).ToArray();
```

Comment: Just a remark : be careful with NULL values when doing concatenation.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus `null` will be fine (or should be)

Comment: if `d.Forname` is null and `d.Surname` is not, for example, you will get a null result, not `d.Surname`

Comment: because it will generate something like `select NULL + ' ' + 'test';` And you can test this kind of query

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus OK, I'll fix that.

Answer (score 2):

because it doesn't exist in your db, so linq2entities can't generate proper sql

so

**Solution1**

concatenate in your query, *using a coalesce operator* (if you don't and one part is NULL, all will be null).

```
select d.ForeName ?? string.Empty + " " + d.Surname ?? string.Empty
```

**Solution2**

```
  select d.Forename, d.Surname
```

and you will be able to use `FullName` when you'll have enumerated the Queryable

**Solution3**

Use a computed column